# Virtualenv ". venv/bin/activate" vs "source venv/bin/activate"

Tags: python, virtualenv

lets say i created a virtualenv called venv (virtualenv venv)

From reading tutorials, i read there are 2 ways to activate virtual env:

1. `. venv/bin/activate`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`

I think they both accomplish the same thing, but i dont understand whats going on.

Also for number 1, doesnt the "." just mean the current folder?  but it doesnt work if i just type in "venv/bin/activate" without the "."

any help would be great!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`.` and `source` do exactly the same thing, with the only difference being that while `source` is more readable, it may not be available in all shells.

The command runs the contents of the script within the current shell, and this is important in the case of `activate`, because one of the things that the script does is exports and modifies environment variables within your current shell.

If you were to run it using `./path/to/activate`, the script will be run within a subshell and all environment variables that are set will be lost once the script completes and the subshell terminates.

> *Also for number 1, doesn't the "." just mean the current folder?*

`.` has a different meaning depending on the context. It only means "current folder" when used as (or part of) a path.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_%28Unix%29:

> The dot command is not to be confused with a [dot file, which is a dot-prefixed hidden file or hidden directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_file).

---

As an aside, I would suggest that you take a look at [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/) which provides additional wrapper commands that make `virtualenv` much easier to use.

Using `virtualenvwrapper`, switching to an evironment is done simply by calling:

```
workon YOUR_ENV
```

Comment: @JohnP oops. I may have accidentally edited that out. Let me put it back in.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu you must beware of its use of Dash and in earlier versions /bin/bash pointed at dash (not sure if it still does), hence source didnt work, but . worked fine.

Comment: I use `source venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 4):

The `.` command is essentially an alias for the `source`. They both execute a given script in the current shell without forking a new shell.

[Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/execute-shell-script/) are some nice examples.

Comment: Other way around: `.` is the [POSIX-specified command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/dot.html) that works everywhere, `source` is the alias (available on a subset of shells).